# How to use regex search/replace in vs code to identify sentences within a paragraph and start each on new line

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, latex

I'm writing latex in vscode and a need to start each sentence on a new line in order to git git tracking. How to use regex regex search/replace in vs code to Identify sentences within a paragraph start each with new line

Answer (score 0):

None of the methods mentioned in other posts worked for me. The way to go was to search for end of sentences using regex pattern `[.|?|!]\s` and replacing with `.\n`

[image]